# ASP.NET SQL Membership checking failed login attempts using loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web Application, `Web.config` file is set to enable locking:              `maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="8"`.

However, I do not want to simply lock out a user, I want to display a message after 4 attempts that the account will be lock after X amount of additional failed attempts.

*Example: Lets say the user has 4 failed attempt; they'll see a message warning that account will be lock (I do not want to specify the total attempts) just that too many failures will result to account being lock.*

After 8 failed attempts the user gets a message that the account is locked.

To do this I decided to use a `While Loop`, So I created the loop like this:
I usually create a rough draft and if the code works then I add it to my project.

I already have the log-in and everything else working, just this loop. If I can find where I am going wrong with the loop then I can do all the DB checking and locking the account.

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text))
  {
  FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text, chkMemory.Checked);
    }
    else
    {
      ltrStatusMsg.Text = "* InValid Login";
    }
```

The problem is this code works in the console APP but when I tried writing it in a button event it fails.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int loginAttempts = 0;
        int maxLoginAttempt = 8;

        while (loginAttempts < maxLoginAttempt)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
            Console.ReadLine();

            if (loginAttempts == 3)
            {
                loginAttempts++;

                Console.Write("Lock Warning :");
            }

            loginAttempts++;
        }

        Console.Write("Account Locked: ");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

*Example: In Button Event:*
*Note: I have changed this code multiple times to find my problem.*

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int loginAttempts = 0;
            int maxLoginAttempt = 8;

        while (loginAttempts < maxLoginAttempt & txtPassword.Text != "Test")
        {
            if (loginAttempts == 3)
            {
                loginAttempts++;

                ltrStatusMsg.Text = "Lock Warning";
            }

            loginAttempts++;
        }

        ltrStatusMsg.Text = "Account Locked";
    }
```

Comment: i think on postback the variable values are intilized back to zero.Use a breakpoint to check

Comment: we can achieve this by assigning the current login attempt value to session and also through if condition. looping is not required...

Comment: Wont I have to retrieve that from the DB? That sounds like a great idea because I am already checking the DB to validate the user log-in on each attempt anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this....

```
protected ovoid Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    Session["mloginAttempts"] = 0;
    Session["maxLoginAttempt"] = 8;
  }
}
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int mLoginAttempt = Convert.ToInt32(Session["mloginAttempts"]);
  int maxLoginAttempt = Convert.ToInt32(Session["maxLoginAttempt"]);

  if(loginAttempts < maxLoginAttempt & txtPassword.Text != "Test")
  {
    if (loginAttempts == 3)
    {
      Session["mloginAttempts"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["mloginAttempts"]) + 1;
      ltrStatusMsg.Text = "Lock Warning";
    }
    Session["mloginAttempts"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["mloginAttempts"]) + 1;
  }
  else
  {
    ltrStatusMsg.Text = "Account Locked";
  } 
}
```

Comment: Anna P. This works beautifully. And Thank you so much, the Session did the trick. However, I think I am simply going to get the value directly from the DB because I am already making DB calls for each login attempt. The SQL Server Membership stores the failed attempt value in the aspnet_Membership table which I have written a Method to get. But your solution above is something I can keep in my box of tools. Thoughts??